# Angular 8: Using service to create dynamic component. Error: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined

Tags: angular, components, angular8

I am trying to use a service to create dynamic components. I didn't have issues creating dynamic component when the code was in a component. When I move my code to a service I get an error about createComponent not found.

I have my function call in  'ngAfterViewInit', this was most people issues were when I looking for solutions. I been trying to figure out why my code doesn't work when I put it in a service. I have also tried making a director and that didn't work as well.

Here is the code in a stack blitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikshag

The component and the service code is below.

app.component

```
import { GenService } from './gen.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';

 constructor(private gen: GenService) { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.gen.createComp("yo");
  }

}
```

service

```
import { Injectable, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild,ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GenService {

  @ViewChild('container', { static: true }) newsHost: ViewContainerRef; //this allow the targeting needed to add component


  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }


  createComp(message) {
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
    let componentRef = this.newsHost.createComponent(componentFactory);//adds it to the screen

  }//end of bot reply

}
```

child component is just the default that says it works.

Comment: I'm surprised to see a `@ViewChild` inside a service, it should be a component thing... Where did you find this ?

Comment: @Random i can't even remember the site i found some of this from. I think the code i found was some angular 2... so not 100% helpful. I am new to angular as well. Been trying to make a service where I can call it to make dynamic components. I haven't had any luck to find someone else using a service.

Comment: Try moving the @ViewChild in your AppComponent, giving it as a parameter to the service (`this.gen.createComp("yo", this.newsHost)`)

Comment: Sadly that didn't help.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikshag

Comment: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-dynamic-components/

This seemed to work

Answer (score 1):

This is not that simple. The topic you are reading ([angular-dynamic-components](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-dynamic-components/)) is quite long.

Have a look to `src/app/dialog/insertion.directive.ts`, which is then refered in the ng-template using its selector (whereas you used a `container` selector which does not map to any angular directive).
This directive has `viewContainerRef` injected, which is what is used to have access to the method `createComponent`.
The ViewChild is quite more complex too: `@ViewChild(InsertionDirective) insertionPoint: InsertionDirective`.

So the steps you have to do are:

1. Make a Directive as stated in the blog
2. Use its selector in the `<ng-template>` tag
3. Update your `@ViewChild` using your directive class
4. access `viewContainerRef` of your directive (which has to be public) to use `createComponent` method

Answer (score 0):

> [malcoded.com/posts/angular-dynamic-components](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-dynamic-components/) This seemed to work –
> Bratchan
> Sep 19, 2019

Search `let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(xxxxx);`
in Bratchan's link. Use `resolveComponentFactory`, before`createComponent`.

And about `createComponent`, Bratchan's link works on `angular 10.x.x`.
If your `package.json` show your project angular version is `14.x.x`, you maybe need to see [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)